# Dynamically build breadcrumbs from router

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I am trying to build a breadcrumbs path for my application, with the less amount of code possible.

For that, I am listening to router events, and getting the data from the current route snapshot (assuming every route has a crumb data).

Right now, I have a working solution, building the route automatically.

But it doesn't work as soon as the user navigates : I don't know how to detect the direction of the routing (down the tree, or up), so I don't know how to add/remove the items from the crumbs.

I thought about going through the whole tree again (in case the user doesn't navigate from a parent to a child - or vice versa -), but I don't know how to do that either.

I have created a simple stackblitz to show my issue :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysbzkp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

The related code of the tree reading :

```js
constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
) {
  this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof ActivationStart),
    map((event: ActivationStart) => event.snapshot.data),
    map(data => data && data.crumb || undefined),
    filter(v => !!v),
  ).subscribe(crumb => this.crumbs.push(crumb));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I figured out the answer myself.

Instead of `ActivationStart`, the router should listen to `ActivationEnd`, but also `NavigationEnd`.

On activation end, the router sends events in reverse order, containing all the routes.

By putting them in a buffer, it becomes possible to reverse the buffer on navigation end, then clear it, resulting in a trail of crumbs that is coherent with the application.

Here is the stackblitz and the related code :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjg2ja?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```js
let buffer = [];

this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(event => event instanceof ActivationEnd),
  map((event: ActivationEnd) => event.snapshot.data),
  map(data => data && data.crumb || undefined),
  filter(v => !!v),
).subscribe(crumb => buffer.push(crumb));

this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
).subscribe(event => {
  this.crumbs = buffer.reverse();
  buffer = [];
});
```